# How to open Context menu on list item click if list view open in popup window

Tags: android

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shopping_list_layout, null);

            Button cancel_btn = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
            Button clear_list_btn = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.clear_list);
            Button remind_me_btn = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.calender_btn);
            Button sent_mail_btn = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.mail_btn);
            Button all_addto_cart_btn = (Button) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.add_to_cart);

            TextView oderable_no_of_products = (TextView) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.orderable_product_no);
            TextView oderable_products_price = (TextView) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.oderable_product_price);

            final TextView no_of_product = (TextView) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.no_of_product_inshopping_list);
            final TextView total_price_in_shopinglist = (TextView) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.total_sum);

            final ListView shopping_listview = (ListView) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.shopping_listview);

            final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 1105, 717, true);
            pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

            LoadProductsForShoppingList shopping_list_obj = new LoadProductsForShoppingList(
                    DynamicTableActivity.this, pw, ac.getImageloder(),
                    shopping_listview, no_of_product, total_price_in_shopinglist,
                    oderable_no_of_products, oderable_products_price);
            shopping_list_obj.execute(Constant.shopping_list_query);

            cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    pw.dismiss();
                }

            });

            all_addto_cart_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // add all products list to cart
                    addAllProductsToCartFromShoppingList();
                }

            });

            clear_list_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // clear shopping list
                    clearShoopingList(shopping_listview, no_of_product,
                            total_price_in_shopinglist);
                }

            });
```

`How to open Context menu on list item click if list view open in popup window .

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
shopping_listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
```

on the long click show the dialog with list.....

Comment: but i have a number item in single cell is it detected by list view...??

Comment: "number items in single row" not get

Comment: i am using button,image view textview in single cell of list view so need to register perticular view for context menu by regiterforcontextmenu(any view).

Comment: you need contextmenu on all items ?

Comment: yes ,but problem is that when i open list view in any activity it works gerat but whne i open it in popup window it is unable to open context mneu..

Comment: for each view you need View.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { for each view

Comment: not for each view ... i am taking relative layout in which i have wrap all view so i want when press relative layout it show context menu but according to you i have register this relative layout for context menu..but no appropriated result... i have used above method as u given but no result..

Comment: so you want context menu to one layout " relative layout" ? right?

Comment: in onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view ... you can get the relative layout by view.findViewByID(<relative layout id>)

Comment: in your case relative  layout is root of the list row so view coming in argument is  relative  layout........

Comment: if i used this method in adapter i can detect this relative layout..by holder.relative_layout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
         @Override
         public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Successfully Add To Cart",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return true;
         }
     });

Comment: but at this stage how to open context menu on logn press..?

Comment: this one is the last option for that.....but i keep this question if any solution ...just like contextmenu..

Comment: any problem with this solution ?